# How to access 'this' from a function in a promise chain in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If I replace '=>' with 'function' in the following JavaScript code

```
            fetch(sendUrl, {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: ...
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                else {
                    this.actionMessage = "Cannot get the response from the server. ': " + response.statusText + "'";
                    this.status = "error";
                }
            }).then ...
```

so it becomes

```
            fetch(sendUrl, {
                method: "post",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: ...
            }).then(function(response) {
                if (response.status == 200) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                else {
                    this.actionMessage = "Cannot get the response from the server. ': " + response.statusText + "'";
                    this.status = "error";
                }
            }).then ...
```

'this' becomes undefined inside the function and I am getting an error like 'Unable to set a property of undefined or null reference'.

How to make this work?

(I need to replace replace '=>' with 'function', because looks like IE does not understand '=>').

Comment: `function () { ... }.bind(this)`

Comment: Use http://babeljs.io to make it work on IE. Don't write bad code just because some browsers can't understand it, write modern code and let your computer transpile it to something opder browser do understand.

Comment: @JonasWilms it is a good idea

Comment: @JonasWilms does babeljs help when a browser does not support 'fetch' ?

Comment: yes, it does. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `this`

```
function() {
  // contents
}
```

to

```
(function() {
  // contents
}).bind(this)
```